# iMovie export settings - what *exactly* do they do?

Tags: video, imovie, encoding, video-editing

In iMovie 10, the export options are limited to:

- Format (Video and Audio, Audio Only)
- Resolution (540p, 720p, 1080p, sometimes 4k)
- Quality (Low, Medium, High, Best (ProRes), Custom)
- Compress (Faster, Better Quality)

Most of my videos are just music coupled with an obligatory still image so I can put them on YouTube. Therefore, I want to maximize audio quality and keep the resolution at a decent level, but the framerate would ideally be zero.

Critically, I can't find any indication of **whether the Quality and Compress options affect both audio and video or just the video output,** nor can my ear tell if there's a difference at different settings. How, precisely, do these two options compress the video?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your above question, but you can theoretically just output in the highest available quality, then use Handbrake to re-encode with optimal settings for a still image. Ideally you'd use ffmpeg to generate the mp4 itself, having it copy the audio without re-encoding.

Comment: To (sort of) help you in answering your original question: you can use an app called "MediaInfo" (or ffprobe via command line) to show you how your video and audio have been encoded. Export with each of iMovie's settings and compare the differences